# Generate multiple contour fills inside axis environment

Tags: pgfplots

I try to create multiple aligned contour plots inside one coordinate system using pgfplots. However pdflatex seems to freeze for multiple executions of the "contour filled" option.
I faked the output by using the "surf" option, so you can see a low quality example of what i expect with contour filled. Contour filled also works with only one cell, as seen in the other image. In the code you can change `\vardim` to `1` to see just one cell. I really need to auto-generate such a plot based on the data in `\tabpx,\tabpy,\tabqx,\tabpy`. Do you know what is causing the the picture to freeze my pdflatex or if there exist alternative methods to get to the desired results?

[image: using surf]
[image: One cell]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.9]
        \def\tabpx{%
            {%
            0,3,5,4.3,5.2
            }%
        }
        \def\tabpy{%
            {%
            1.5,3,5,3.1,0
            }%
        }
        \def\tabqx{%
            {%
            0.0,4,6,7.0,8
            }%
        }
        \def\tabqy{%
            {%
            0.0,0,1,4.9,0
            }%
        }
        \tikzmath{
        \eps=3; \vardim= 3; % change here
        \vardimlow = \vardim - 1; \vardimsquared = \vardim^2 - 1;
        \pox=0; \ptx=1; \poy=0; \pty=1;
        \qox=0; \qtx=1; \qoy=0; \qtyy=1;
        \essss = 0; \teee = 0;
        }
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            domain = 0:3,
            zmax=16,
            shader = interp,
            colormap={gray}{rgb=(1,1,1), rgb=(0.5,0.5,0.5)},
            unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
            xmin=0,xmax=3,ymin=0,ymax=3,
            xlabel=$s$,
            ylabel=$t$,
            axis y line*=left,
            axis x line*=bottom]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\vardimsquared}
            {
                \tikzmath{
                    \essss = {Mod(#1,\vardim)};
                    \teee = (#1 - \essss) / \vardim;
                    \soh = \essss + 1;
                    \toh = \teee + 1;
                    \pox = {\tabpx[\essss]};
                    \ptx = {\tabpx[\soh]};
                    \poy = {\tabpy[\essss]};
                    \pty = {\tabpy[\soh]};
                    \qox = {\tabqx[\teee]};
                    \qtx = {\tabqx[\toh]};
                    \qoy = {\tabqy[\teee]};
                    \qtyy = {\tabqy[\toh]};
                };
                \addplot3
                [
                    % surf, %-> works
                    contour filled={number = 2, labels={false}, levels={\eps}}, % problem
                    thick,
                    domain = \essss:\soh,
                    restrict x to domain=\essss:\soh,
                    y domain = \teee:\toh,
                    samples=10
                ]
                {   
                    sqrt((((1-(x-\essss))*\pox + (x-\essss)*\ptx) - ((1-(x-\essss))*\qox + (x-\essss)*\qtx))^2+(((1-(y-\teee))*\poy + (y-\teee)*\pty) - ((1-(y-\teee))*\qoy + (y-\teee)*\qtyy))^2)
                };
                \draw[color=red] (\essss,\teee) rectangle (\soh,\toh);
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\small \textit{Just one cell}.}
    \label{fig:example}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

EDIT 1:
I found this error in the logs (the program was still running forever):
`! Package pgfplots Error: No such element: \pgfplotsarrayselect-1\of{pgfpl@cm@internal:contourfilled@X}.`
Here is a minimal working example for the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            domain = 0:2,
            xmin=0,xmax=2,ymin=0,ymax=2]
            \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,1}
            {
                \addplot3
                [
                contour filled={number = 1, labels={false}, levels={0.25}}, % problem
                domain = #1:{#1 + 1},
                y domain = 0:1,
                samples=15
                ]
                { sqrt((x- #1 -0.5)^2+(y-0.5)^2) };
            }
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Please create a Minimal Working Example showing your problem. Use a dummy function, if your actual function is not the problem, eliminate all constants and math env., if it is not the problem, remove all options not related to the problem, do not use fig. env., ....

Comment: @hpekristiansen I left the original code in the post, because it shows what i want to achieve, if somebody has a different idea. But i put a Minimal Working Example for the pgfplots issue in EDIT 1 at the bottom.

Comment: @Mangudai: Great approach. Now it is clear, that it is `pgfplotsinvokeforeach` in combination with `contour filled` that is the problem. I do not know the error or why it is there - someone smarter than me will help. Is it an option for you to add several `\addplot3` instead of using a loop?

Comment: @hpekristiansen The resulting diagram is called the "free space diagram" for two polygonal curves given as tabular input. Ideally i wanted the dimensions to be dynamic, but i guess in the worst case i could manually copy each plot. My current example curves are low dimensional, so it's possible with like 5x5 plots.

I'm currently investigating another method, because it seems, when there is no contour in all in the current cell, the area goes white instead of the desired gray. I will try to calculate the shape analytically(always an affine transformation of an ellipse) and draw it per cell.